# OpenGL why does repeating texture over same amount of fragments may cost performance?

Tags: opengl

I have a quad of unitary size rendered with seamless texture and with texture repetition enabled.

For the texture coordinates I get it from the position.
So I can artificially raise the texture resolution by multiplying the texture coordinates by a factor of N, which will make the texture repeat over the quad N*N times.

In my code my texture is a normal map and there is specular light calculation with it in fragment shader. And I noticed more I multiply the texture coordinates more my performance drops, however it seems the performance drop is constant after a certain value (no difference between N = 1024 and N = 10240 for example)

What I do not understand is that the quad size stays the same, the texture size is the same, why does multiplying texture coordinates cost me performance over the same amount of fragments ?

Comment: Do you use mipmapping? Which filter mode is used? data and cache locality might play a role here. The larger N gets the further away in the texture are neighbouring fragments.

Comment: No mipmapping, I use GL_LINEAR for filtering for both min & mag filters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> No mipmapping, I use `GL_LINEAR` for filtering for both min & mag filters.

When scale increases, adjacent pixels in your fragment shader correspond to texels in your texture that are far apart. With GL_LINEAR, this means that the texels are not only far apart in the texture, but they are also far apart in memory.

With scale closer to 1:1, adjacent pixels in your fragment shader will be taken from texels that are also close together. This means they will be close together in memory, which means better memory locality. This requires fewer fetches from memory.

Mipmapped textures do not have this problem, and they often look better too because they don't have the aliasing problems you see with GL_LINEAR minification.

### Simulating it on the CPU

The CPU has the same problem with memory fetches.

```
float sum(float *arr, int size, int stride, int count) {
    int pos = 0;
    float sum = 0.0f;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        pos = (pos + stride) % size;
        sum += arr[pos];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

As `stride` increases, the performance gets worse. This happens for the same reason that your fragment shader performance gets worse, even though it's happening on the CPU.